# Construct an 'is_template_instantiable' type trait in C++

Tags: c++, templates, variadic-templates, c++17, type-traits

Is it possible to construct a type trait in C++ that checks if a given template type is instantiable with the given types as template parameters? If it is possible, how could it be done?

For example:

```
static_assert(is_template_instantiable_v<std::optional, int, int>);
static_assert(is_template_instantiable_v<std::vector, double>);
```

The first assert would fail because [`std::optional`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional) expects only a single template parameter. The second assert does not fail, [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) may be instantiated with only a single template parameter because its second template parameter has a default.

---

If the above is possible, would it be possible to let the type trait be false in the following case (and not trigger a compile error):

```
static_assert(is_template_instantiable_v<std::vector, int &>);
```

Because `std::vector` may not be instantiated with a reference as its value type.

---

My guess is the first example may be feasible to replicate while the second cannot be done using only standard C++ code.

Comment: The second part is impossible without concepts, because the error (if any) is not in the immediate context of deduction.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume that the first requirement is doable with an approach based on [detection idiom](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/is_detected):

```
namespace detail
{
    template<template<typename...> typename T, typename AlwaysVoid, typename... Ts>
    struct is_template_instantiable :
        std::false_type {};

    template<template<typename...> typename T, typename... Ts>
    struct is_template_instantiable<T, std::void_t<T<Ts...>>, Ts...> :
        std::true_type {};

    template<template<typename...> typename T, typename... Ts>
    inline constexpr auto is_template_instantiable_v =
        is_template_instantiable<T, void, Ts...>::value;
}
```

Then, with:

```
template<typename T = void>
struct X{};
```

It produces:

```
static_assert(detail::is_template_instantiable_v<X>);
static_assert(detail::is_template_instantiable_v<X, void>);
static_assert(!detail::is_template_instantiable_v<X, void, int>);
```

[**EXAMPLE**](https://godbolt.org/g/P5KYrM)

However, with this type trait I am not able to solve the second challenge...

Comment: Note that this doesn't actually instantiate the class template.  Something like `std::void_t<decltype(sizeof(T<Ts...>))>` would attempt to instantiate it, but that just gets you a bunch of nasty errors "not in the immediate context" for cases like `<std::vector, int&>` since most class templates are not SFINAE-friendly.  Maybe the standard class templates will someday be more SFINAE-friendly now that Concepts are coming...

Comment: This seems to solve the question I posed. Only one thing: on my local system with Ubuntu and Clang 6.0.0, the `is_template_instantiable_v` works but `is_template_instantiable<...>::value` does not. Any reason why that might be?

Comment: @MaartenBamelis you probably miss `void` which is specified explicitly when variable template is defined.

Comment: @EdgarRokjān That was exactly it. I assumed `std::void_t` would be part of the solution but I could not figure out how to combine it with the variadic template parameters. Thanks for putting in the effort!

Comment: @aschepler Could I write my own template classes in a more SFINAE-friendly way to also solve the second challenge? Or would that just boil down to always adding a kind of `allows_template_parameters` member that would then be used in the `is_template_instantiable` type trait?

Comment: @MaartenBamelis Yes, it's possible in C++17 to add requirements to a class template in a way that will work directly with this `is_template_instantiable_v`, using something like `template</*other params...*/, std::void_t</*constraints...*/>*=nullptr> class`.  Depending on how detailed you want the constraints to be, this could get tedious - like IsAllocator has lots of requirements.  Concepts will provide a nicer way to write them, and a good library of commonly used concepts would be quite helpful.